# How can I get more space available?

Tags: size

I created a Virtual Machine (using VirtualBox) with 20 Gb disk size so I could use Ubuntu 64-bit on a Mac. 
I needed Ubuntu for running Xilinx ISE 14.7. I downloaded the file but when I tried to install it said I needed 20362 MB Disk Space but I only had 6499 MB.

Then I tried to increase the disk size of the virtual machine and I increased it a lot... 
But when I tried again the same message appeared "I needed 20362 Mb and only had 6499 Mb"... But I looked for the settings of my virtual machine and I have indeed increased the disk memory...

My Optical Drive says also [Empty] (I don't know if that's relevant)...

What am I doing wrong?
Do I need to create a Virtual Machine again? If so please let me know what is the size I need.

thanks

Comment: It might help if you were to post a screenshot (normally, I hate those, but I suppose VB uses a GUI) of the settings of your VB. If I understand correctly, you meant to create a VB of size 20 Gb, but some program you are trying to install says it only has 6499 Mb available. What size do *you* think the VB is?

Answer (score 1):

From the 20 or so at least part is taken by the installation of the OS, and you probably also have one or more gigabyte disc space taken by the swap space (the size for that partition depends on the RAM memory you allocated for your VM).

If you increase the size of the VM disc, that doesn't increase the size of the filesystem that was created during installation of Ubuntu. You would need to repartition the drive from within Ubuntu (which is not entirely trivial, especially if the disc has a swap partition after the main one) and then resize the filesystem. Without detailed information on how your current disc is partitioned, it would be guesswork on how to describe that.

What I recommend is making a new Virtualbox VM. Allocate 50Gb or even more. In the default setup the actual file that is the disc for the VM only gets the size that is taken. So assuming you install 12Gb in software after installation of Ubuntu (which seems a lot to me) and have a 2Gb swap partition you'll have a file that is around 14Gb big, and after installation of Xilinx this should grow to a maximum of 35Gb or so (probably less). So that leaves some space to grow.

Reinstallation probably takes more time, but is less error prone than trying to resize your partitions and filesystem.

Comment: Hello! Thanks very much for your help. Anyway do you think I will have problems if I create a machine with 2TB (the maximum value) but dinamically allocated?

Comment: I don't think that 2Tb discs create a problem. In any event you need to make sure you keep an eye on the free space of the partition where you put the VM disc files.